# Passing object to another class in java

Tags: java, swing

I have my main class lets call it MainGUI
It contains the following

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
UserUI aGui = new UserUI(user);
}
```

user object has username and password
I need to pass this to UserUI and display the User name and password in a textArea
So far I am not getting anything  to appear in my UserUI text Area, The UserUI class looks like this:

```
package Details;

public class UserUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 User user;

    public UserUI() {
        initComponents();

    }


    public void setUser(User user){

        if(user.getName().equals("Bob")){
            jTextArea1.setText(user.getName());
        }
    }

  UserUI(User user) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
   }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UserUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UserUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UserUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UserUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new UserUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I don't see a public constructor that takes parameters

Comment: @csmckelvey - Actually there's one and it's doing precisely nothing.

Comment: Based on posted code the sequence should be: `UserUI aGui = new UserUI(); aGui.setUser(user); aGUI.setVisible(true);`.

Comment: Thanks alot works now

Answer (score 2):

In `UserUI(User user)` call `this()`

```
UserUI(User user) {
    this();
    this.user = user;
    setUser(user);
}
```

Comment: See update...nothing's going to be displayed unless you apply the details of the user to the UI...

Comment: .. or call `setUser()` method, as `dic19` has suggested.

Comment: @PM77-1 Dam that codes hard to read...or is it just to early :P